# Compact operator from $l_2$ to $l_1$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\{\alpha_n\} $ be the sequence of complex nubers. Operator $A:l_2\to l_1$ $A(x_n)\to \alpha_n x_n$. When A is compact.
Using Holder's inequality and definition of compact operator as an operator when image of bounded is totaly bounded easy to proof that if $\alpha\in l_2$ A is compact. But in opposite, i can not proof that if A compact, $\alpha\in l_2$.

Answer (score 2):

$T$ is not even well-defined operator if $(\alpha_n) \notin l^{2}$. It is well known that $\sum |\alpha_n x_n| <\infty$ for  all $(x_n) \in l^{2}$ implies that $(\alpha_n) \in l^{2}$. [I suggest that you search this site for a proof. It has appeared many times in the recent past].